# why the global state value always undefined even already setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I define a array value with 0 element in react state like this:

```
state = {
    formValues: {
      activityStatusArray:[],
      createdStartTime: '',
      createdEndTime: '',
      activityStartTime: '',
      activityEndTime: '',
    }
  };
```

the `activityStatusArray` always undefined even I setState in the next code:

```
if(localFormValues.activityStatus===1){
            this.setState({
              formValues: {
                activityStatusArray: [1]
              }
            },()=>{
              this.dispathSerach(fieldsValue,formValues);
            });
          }
```

where is going wrong and what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: `formValues` doesnt have `activityStatus`!

Comment: What `activityStatusArray` is always undefined?

Comment: you have to use `this.state.formValues.activityStatusArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define state like below:

```
this.state = {
    formValues: {
      activityStatusArray:[],
      createdStartTime: '',
      createdEndTime: '',
      activityStartTime: '',
      activityEndTime: '',
    }
  };
```

And use the state like this:

```
if(this.state.formValues.activityStatus===1){
        this.setState(prevState => {
          formValues: {
            ...prevState.formValues,
            activityStatusArray: [1]
          }
        },()=>{
          this.dispathSerach(fieldsValue,this.state.formValues);
        });
      }
```